# Saving ngram objects in a dataframe

Tags: r, n-gram

```
require(ngram)
require(stringr)
res<-readLines("text1.txt")
wordlength=0

for(j in 1:length(res) ){
temp<-sapply(strsplit(res[j]," "), length)
 if (temp>=wordlength) {
    wordlength=temp
 }
}

rm("temp")
data<-data.frame

for(i in 1:length(res) ){
x<-res[i]
ng<-ngram(x,n=2)
temp<-babble(ng,genlen=500,seed=123)
data[i]<-ngram(temp,n=2)
}

get.ngrams(ngram(bab[1,],n=2))
babng<-matrix(nrow=length(res),wordlength)
```

I'm trying to save my ngram data in a data frame from this loop, I've also tried to save it in a matrix but this error is showing:

```
"object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"
```

I want to get the frequency distribution of the every 2gram element from the babbler. Sorry for my messy coding. I'm new to R.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you call:

```
data<-data.frame
```

which assigns the function `data.frame` to the variable `data`.  Later, you call `data[i]<-ngram(temp,n=2)` which is causing the error, because the function assigned to the variable `data` cannot be sub-setted using the subset operator `[`.  You probably want to create a data.frame object and assign it to the variable `data` by *calling* the function `data.frame` via:

```
data<-data.frame()
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to obtain the frequencies from the 2gram object for every pairs. So merely saving the 2gram data in the frame won't do the trick I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This will also do it quite easily:

```
require(quanteda)
Bigrams <- tokenize(toLower(res), ngrams = 2)
as.data.frame(table(Bigrams))
```

You can do this for more than one document, if `res` is a character vector of documents, using

```
BigramDfm <- dfm(res, ngrams = 2)
as.data.frame(BigramDfm)
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Ken! I saved it using the row names of the term document matrix, but yours is robust.

Answer (score 0):

2 years later but ....
Ignoring the specifics of your code probably due to the little familiarity with R you declare (and with Quanteda also I would guess)

```
d1 <- dfm("simple sample text", ngrams = 2)
d2 <- textstat_frequency(d1)
class(d2)
# [1] "frequency"  "textstat"   "data.frame"
d2
#         feature frequency rank docfreq group
# 1 simple_sample         1    1       1   all
# 2   sample_text         1    2       1   all
```

Unless there are specific reasons not to the text can be read in one shot, 
if there aren't special reasons not to, probably [readtext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readtext/), synergic with Quanteda, would be the best choice